# How to prevent a UITableView from scrolling up past its initial origin?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Currently, I have set up a `UITableView` below a `UIView` whose origin is (0, 287) in an example of an iPhone 7.

This is achieved using the following sample code:

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 && imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant == 223
        {
            return
        }

        if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0
        {
            var sd = imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant + abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
            if (sd < 223 )
            {
                print("path111    1")

                self.dataTableView.contentOffset = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0  )

                return
            }
            else
            {
                imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant -= abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
            }

            view.layoutIfNeeded()

            self.dataTableView.contentOffset = .zero
            return
        }

        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 && imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant >= initialContainerImageViewHeight * 2
        {
            self.dataTableView.contentOffset = .zero

            return
        }
        else
        {
            imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant += abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y)

            view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }

    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)
    {
        resetContainerViewSize()
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        resetContainerViewSize()
    }
}

func resetContainerViewSize()
{
    imageContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant = initialContainerImageViewHeight

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
                   options: .curveEaseInOut,
                   animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: nil)
}
```

If I slowly scroll down, then slowly scroll up, the `UITableView` will stop at the origin and go no further up, and never enters the condition `if (sd < 223 )`....like so:

[image]

However, if I scroll down, and pull up fast, once the top of the section header reaches the initial origin of (0, 287), the `UITableView` will scroll a bit further up and enters the condition `if (sd < 223 )`, because once I let go, the `UITableView` will **bounce** back down to its origin.....like so:

[image]

If I pull up on the `UITableView` even faster, it will scroll **even further** up and bounce back down once I let go of the `UITableView`:

[image]

I've found some similar questions:

1. [Stop UITableView over scroll at top & bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937764/stop-uitableview-over-scroll-at-top-bottom)
2. [Limit the scroll for UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805615/limit-the-scroll-for-uitableview)
3. [Prevent UITableView scrolling below a certain point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624708/prevent-uitableview-scrolling-below-a-certain-point)

I've tried the suggested solution to a variation, by disabling `alwaysBounceVertical` and `bounces`, but this just disables scrolling altogether, which is **not** what I want.

Since `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, I've always tried setting `scrollView.contentOffset = .zero` within the condition `if(sd < 223 )`, which also did not help.

How would I prevent the `UITableView` from being pulled up past its initial origin points, i.e. (0, 287)?

I've included a sample project: [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fifkqy63a2fyw87/Shortcuts.rtdata?dl=0)

Comment: what about `self.tableview.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;` see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771443/limit-uitableview-scroll-speed-like-instagram-does-it

Comment: @Anbu.karthik the `UITableView` scrolling still contains the same issue